# iOS - unlimited scrolling

Tags: ios, vertical-scrolling

I'm developing a very simple app for iOS and I have a view with text and an image. When I simulate the app, vertical scrolling does not show all picture. Is it possible to get unlimited scrolling? If yes, could you explain me step-by-step how to obtain it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "unlimited scrolling" really the problem to solve or is it "allow showing all pictures"?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's the solution. What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried using UITableView delegate functions by giving a height to footer ??

Comment: Ehm, I need step-by-step help...

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Web service? Core Data? How are you putting into the UITableView? We really need more information.

Comment: Let me say what I did: in Main.Storyboard I inserted a View Controller. On this View I created a text field and an image space. This is my basic View, I populated both text field and image and app starts on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I want you to try is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20.0f;
}
```

Add this code along with other table view functions and see if it resolves.

**EDIT**

As I understood you can adjust the UIScrollView's content offset, like this (any where probably in viewDidLoad):

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[yourScrollViewInstance setContentSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height * 2)];
```

Here `rect.size.height * 2` will be adjusted in a way that shows the content perfectly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where I have to put that code? I have no table in that "view", it is: view -> scroll view -> text view -> image view. Sorry if i'm wasting your time, I'm really noob but I would to learn.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking at tableview cell, which is going to load inside tableview ?

Comment: I think I'm looking a View controller (with a text field and a space for an image).

Comment: Can you share the image that depicts your problem ?

Comment: Nope, I can't get it work. Anyway, thanks for your really appreciate help, I will try to keep studying Objective-C. :-(